# Prevent users from getting url from embedded YouTube video/disable clipboard

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, youtube

I have a website where I embed a YouTube video in an iframe. My problem is that I don't want the user to get the videoID or the link to the video (atleast without opening the console because that's propably impossible).

I already managed to disable the YouTube logo on which one can click at to open the video in a new tab. But there is the context menu if you rightclick on the video where one can copy the video url to his clipboard and so on.

After a lot of research if found out that there is no possibility to disable the context menu somehow because that would be cross-site-scripting.

Another possible method would be to constantly check the users clipboard if there is some string in it containing the videoID. This won't work aswell (except in IE i guess) because there are some restrictions to access the clipboard so i can't find out what the user saves in it (even with flash).

It would also be enough to just check if the clipboard content changed to detect that the user maybe tried to get the videoURL (it's no problem if he finds out the video url as long as I know about it).

Disabling the clipboard at all or spamming it with something else seems impossible too.

I hope there is a solution to my problem, thanks.

Edit:

this is the used HTML including some scripts (aswell as some that are not working)

```
<script>

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        console.log("READY");

        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange() {
        console.log("STATE CHANGED");
    }

</script>

<body>
    <div class="all">

        <?php
            include "parts/header.php";
        ?>

        <div class="player-bg">
            <div class="player">
                <iframe
                    id="player"
                    width="640"
                    height="390"
                    frameborder="0"
                    sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation"
                    src="<?=$embedURL?>">
                </iframe>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="usercontrols-container">
            <form id="form" method="post" action="./views.php" autocomplete="off">
                <input class="textfield" type="text" min="0" name="guessViews"/>
                <a class="button" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit();">Guess</a>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

<script>
    function copy() {
        console.log("copy detected 2");
    }

    document.addEventListener("copy", function() {
        console.log("copy detected 1");
    });
</script>
```

Blakk

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: I added it but its propably nothing special about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event listeners for the copy, and cut events.

```html
You can't copy any text.
<br/>
<textarea>You can't copy any text.</textarea>
<script>
document.body.addEventListener("copy", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 e.stopPropagation();
});
document.body.addEventListener("cut", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 e.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

You could also put the video inside a  tag without controls and add the controls via buttons.

```html
<video width="320" height="240" id="vid">
<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<button onClick="document.getElementById('vid').play()">Play</button>
<br/>
<button onClick="document.getElementById('vid').pause()">Pause</button>
```

You can also cover the iframe with a div overlay and prevent the contextmenu event.

```css
#frame{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#overlay{
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 155px;
  height: 155px;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<iframe width="150" height="150" id="frame">
</iframe>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("overlay").addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I did try to add a event listener to the copy function already but it seems to not be fired if it is used in the custom context menu of youtube. Maybe it is due to the fact that the video is in an iframe. But I will try this in a minute again.

Comment: @BlakkM9 Check my other solution.

Comment: works fine if the url to the mp4 file is known but seems like that is not working for youtube videos. I'm searching if there is a possibility to view a youtube video in a video tag. Another solution is maybe to embed the youtube video in a different player what some other webpage manage to do so its possible but your answer already helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Found a solution with your inspiration: I found something to get the direct link to the YouTube video from the YouTube video URL. Works perfect for me and its even impossible to find the video on YouTube with the page source.

[link](https://gist.github.com/el3zahaby/9e60f1ae3168c38cc0f0054c15cd6a83) if interested.

Comment: @BlakkM9 Great!

Answer (score 0):

Tip: You can add an overlay to the iframe this will prevent also right click. But you need a way to satrt and stop the video with an API.

Example:

```
<div class="player-bg">
            <div class="player">
            <div id="overlay" style="
    width: 560px;
    height: 315px;
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
"></div>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/raa5ki4hVp8" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>            
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I remember testing this when trying to disable the youtube button in the video but somehow it didn't work for me but your solution works fine. But I already found a better fitting solution for me (because I want the user to be able to skip around the video easily) just watch the comment on sdlfyeiwyrw answer if interested.

Comment: Can a similar overlay applied if the user clicks the fullscreen button and watches the video in fullscreen mode?